# Rails Schema Design Software?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, schema

I am presently designing a database schema for use in a Rails 3.1 application.

At the moment, I am using MySQL Workbench to design the schema visually, and then manually translating this to Rails migrations & models.

Can anyone indicate if there are any solutions that will allow a schema to be designed visually and translated automatically (i.e. via script) to Rails?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure visual schema builders are helpful. If you design your models first in terms of the business logic you need, and then add the persistence to it, your architecture will be better (IMHO).

Comment: I find it difficult to visualise my relationships coding directly in Rails, and it's also not that easy to change things around quickly and get good visibility on the models - hence using MySQL Workbench, then manually coding (since I don't use MySQL). Is there perhaps a better visual designer then MySQL Workbench? It is obviously MySQL-specific, so something generic might be easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the "database-first" approach definitely isn't really the preferred way to work with Rails... but if you *really* want to...

If you generate the the tables from your schema you can configure the Rails app's `config/database.yml` file to connect to your database, then call `rake db:schema:dump` which generates the `db/schema.rb` file from the database.  Then you can create a migration and copy the code from `db/schema.rb` into the `change` (or `self.up`) method.

Note that this does not automatically create model classes - you'll have to create these yourself, remembering to `--skip migration` in the `rails generate model`, and possibly needing to make liberal use of the `set_table_name` (to map the model class to the right table name), `alias_attribute` (to map model attributes to the right columns), and perhaps `set_primary_key`.

There were some more complete approaches to this sort of thing for older versions of Rails ([Magic Model Generator](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/) and [reverse_scaffold](https://github.com/ahe/reverse_scaffold) are two that I've found), but I don't know of any that have been upgraded to work with Rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Editor](http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/) is a Mac application that allows you to visually design a DB schema and then export it as something you can easily import as a schema in Rails.

You will still have to create the models yourself.

Comment: SQLEditor now exports a Rails migration file. SQLEditor 2.9 is a visual schema editor the you can export a usable .rb file.This software should do the trick. http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/

Answer (score 0):

I think [Mogwai ERD](http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/index.html) will help you out, there you can design your ERD and convert it in to a DB schema.

And I think there is no software for design Rails schema, it's just that you make your schema adhere to Rails conventions. But of course Rails can be configured to almost any schema.

Answer (score 0):

For rails existing applications or the new application, you can use this for db design
https://dbdiagram.io/

Answer (score 0):

I use [railshelper.com](https://www.railshelper.com) which helps me in a simplistic manner to generate quickly some common rails cli commands !